# ImageJ - compare original and resized image on similarity

Tags: image, image-processing, image-resizing, imagej

Dear Colleagues.
Could you help me please with next question.
I want to resize huge amount of images and substitute original images with resized for saving disk space. But before substitution I want to be sure, that resized image is the same original image but with different dimensions (not white list, not Malevich's square and so on). 
Is there a way to check such similarity to be sure that resizing was successful?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea might be to downscale your image into a tentative down-resed version, then scale it back up to the original size and compare that with the original. If they seem pretty similar, overwrite the original with the tentative conversion, if not, report error.

Here's how you might do that in `bash` with comments. It can be rehashed into other languages of course, or you can use a `system()` to shell out and use this command line version from another language.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Downscale an image and check if correct
# Supply image name as parameter

original="$1"
tentative="t-$$-$original"
echo DEBUG: tentative filename=$tentative

# Get size of original so we can resize back up to that size
origsize=$(identify -format "%G" "$original")
echo DEBUG: origsize=$origsize

# Do downsizing of image, saving result tentatively
convert image.jpg -resize 800x800 "$tentative"

# Test quality/success of conversion by looking at PSNR
PSNR=$(convert "$tentative" -resize $origsize\! "$original" -metric PSNR -format "%[distortion]" -compare info:)
echo DEBUG: PSNR=$PSNR

# PSNR above 20 is pretty indicative of good similarity - use "bc" as shell doesn't do floats
if [ $(echo "$PSNR>20" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
   echo $original looks good
else
   echo $original something wrong
fi
```

One thing to beware of is transparency - don't convert from a GIF or PNG (both of which support transparency) to a JPEG (which doesn't) and then resize and compare - you are asking for trouble. You will see in my script above that I retain the image extension and pre-pend bits to the front rather than the end of the filename.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark. I've tried this method, but it give me strange result. If to compare Original size image and Resized (downscaled) image - I get 74% similarity. But if to compare Original size image with Upscaled to Original size, I get only 4% similarity. Hmmm...

Comment: How did you measure similarity at 4% - using which metric and what scaling? My code doesn't compute or measure any percentages...

Comment: Ou, I used first this command: "convert image1 image2 -compose Difference -composite -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:" But than I used your metric with command: "convert "$tentative" -resize $origsize\! "$original" -metric PSNR -format "%[distortion]" -compare info:" and get about 27,7. Seems it works great. Can I suppose this measure means images are similar? Thank you very much, Mark!

Comment: Mark, don't you know how to implement that command in ImageMagick using Java API (JMagick) or C# API (Magick.Net). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not. However, @dlemstra is on SO and he is the maintainer of the C# implementation of ImageMagick so he may well be able to tell us all  how to do `convert im1.jpg im2.jpg -metric PSNR -format "%[distortion]" info:` if we ask him nicely ;-)

Answer (score 0):

well as far as the size is concerned you can simply check the dimensions 
in matlab
`[x,y]=size(im);`
this will let you know that the if the image has been resized
To check if the image is the same you can use feature extraction such as SURF features.
Extract the surf features, match them if you get 100% ~ 90% match you have the same image!!

Comment: Thanks, Haroon. I'm interesting in using this feature in Java or C# programm. I have found this acticle http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/. If to use command "convert image1 image2 -compose Difference -composite \
           -colorspace gray -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:" it show similarity percent, I think)) It is about 74%. Is it enough to conclude images are the same ? P.S. Almost all images are scanned text documents. Thanks.

Comment: look for Surf Features they will give you better result then your current method.

PS: i have never worked in this regard so i cant be sure about the percentages.